# Always in upper case... (C# winforms)

Tags: c#, key-events

I have a `TextBox` in my form and I added this event on it:

```
private void txtValue_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(e.KeyData.ToString());
        }
```

But it always prints the upper case of the letter even though I entered a lower case letter in the textBox. Please see image below:

[image: my form]

How should I get the right display? Thanks...

Comment: There should also be a property showing if the shift key is pressed

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`KeyDown` and `KeyUp` use `KeyEventArgs`, which exposes the `Keys` enum via the `KeyData` property. The enum does not have representation for lower-case alphabetic values.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.keys.aspx

The `KeyPress` event allows you to get the actual character of the key pressed via `KeyPressEventArgs.KeyChar`.

```
private void txtValue_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
{
    MessageBox.Show(e.KeyChar.ToString());
}
```

Answer (score 3):

If you handle the `KeyPress` event instead, you can examine the `KeyChar` property of `KeyPressEventArgs` to get the correct case.